# How Do You Cause An Optional Element To Be Absent In C# Code Generated With Svcutil.exe's Default Serializer?

Tags: datacontractserializer, svcutil.exe, optional-values

I have a WSDL from a web service server which includes the following in its types:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="countryID" type="xs:int"/>
```

This is supposed to represent an optional int element named countryID.  When I run svcutil.exe (from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin) against it, I get the following generated code:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public int countryID
{
    get
    {
        return this.countryIDField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.countryIDField = value;
    }
}
```

The "IsRequired=true" property is not set on the DataMemberAttribute.  But I don't see a way to indicate that I want a given instance to be absent!  Some googling revealed that I could modify the generated code (which I hate doing) to use "DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false)" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792.aspx?ppud=4).  But if I do this, I cannot use a countryID value of zero, as this will be interpreted as the default value, and no countryID element will be generated!

If I add the "/serializer:XmlSerializer" command line option, the following is generated:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
public int countryID
{
    get
    {
        return this.countryIDField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.countryIDField = value;
    }
}

///
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public bool countryIDSpecified
{
    get
    {
        return this.countryIDFieldSpecified;
    }
    set
    {
        this.countryIDFieldSpecified = value;
    }
}
```

This seems like it should work: I just set countryIDFieldSpecified to "false".

How is this supposed to work with the DataContractSerializer?

Thanks!